# Twitter Locations Filter not working, 406 error

Tags: api, twitter, streaming

so I am trying to limit the Twitter streaming API to only get tweets from the US, and I keep getting a 406 error.

```
    twitterStream.filter(locations = USA)
```

This is my code line for the stream, with the USA coordinates being defined as

```
    USA= [32.67,-124.14,41.76,-73.98]
```

Any ideas? When I put the coordinates in the filter itself, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are specifying latitude/longitude pairs, where you should be specifying longitude/latitude pairs. Try it with `-124.14,32.67,-73.98,41.76` and it should work fine.